# when server restarts all installed jenkins plugins got deleted and all configuration also removed, again it starts from scratch

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I am trying to create Jenkins pod and the agent  in K8s environment. Installed all plugins also configured the kubernetes plugins.
I successfully created the Jenkins Pod and the agent also build the sample job but the issue is
when the server restarts all my installed plugins and the configurations all got removed. Again it start from the scratch asking Admin password and start installing the plugins. How to fix this issue?

I have given all my Yaml files below

Volume.yaml

```
   kind: StorageClass
   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1   
   metadata:
     name: jenkins-storage
   provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
   volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolume
   metadata:
      name: jenkins-pv-volume
      labels:
         type: local
   spec:
     storageClassName: jenkins-storage
     claimRef:
        name: jenkins-pv-claim
        namespace: jenkins
     capacity:
       storage: 1Gi
     accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
     hostPath:
          path: /mnt/jenkins-vol

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
   metadata:
        name: jenkins-pv-claim
        namespace: jenkins
   spec:
     storageClassName: jenkins-storage
     accessModes:
       - ReadWriteOnce
     resources:
       requests:
       storage: 1Gi

   ---------
```

Deployment.Yaml

```
       apiVersion: apps/v1
       kind: Deployment
       metadata:
           name: jenkins
           namespace: jenkins
       spec:
         replicas: 1
         selector:
            matchLabels:
                app: jenkins-server
         template:
           metadata:
             labels:
               app: jenkins-server
           spec:
              securityContext:
                   fsGroup: 1000
                   runAsUser: 1000
              serviceAccountName: jenkins-admin
              containers:
               - name: jenkins
                 image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
                 resources:
                    limits:
                      memory: "3Gi"
                      cpu: "1500m"
                    requests:
                      memory: "500Mi"
                      cpu: "500m"
              ports:
               - name: httpport
                 containerPort: 8080
               - name: jnlpport
                 containerPort: 50000
              livenessProbe:
               httpGet:
                 path: "/login"
                 port: 8080 
               initialDelaySeconds: 90
               periodSeconds: 30
               timeoutSeconds: 10
               failureThreshold: 5
              readinessProbe:
               httpGet:
                 path: "/login"
                 port: 8080
               initialDelaySeconds: 300
               periodSeconds: 30
               timeoutSeconds: 10
               failureThreshold: 3
              volumeMounts:
              - name: jenkins-data
                mountPath: /opt/containerd_workspace/containerd/   
                   io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/284/fs/var/jenkins_home
        volumes:
           - name: jenkins-data
             persistentVolumeClaim:
                 claimName: jenkins-pv-claim
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that the path for `jenkins-data` is not correct, and you are storing the data in Ephemeral Storage. jenkins searches for the data in `/var/jenkins_home`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not able to understand  will you elaborate more on this. In mount path  do i have to define this  ' var/jenkins_home.' ?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using local storage as persistent volume for storing jenkins data. Make sure that the jenkins pod is always bound to the same host.
Verify that persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy is set to 'Retain' to avoid data geting deleted when the pod is restarted.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if we bound the Pod to same host then if the host is failed in such case also we will loose data right ?   Its reclaim policy  Retain only.

Comment: Yes, if the host is failed then you loose the data. That is the limitation of local volumes. Instead consider nfs storage for persistent volume